WPF theme is applied to the first textbox, but not the second
I have a WPF window with a custom theme and a grid that contains two text boxes that are somehow styled differently. I cannot find a difference, but somehow for the first textbox, my theme is not applied.
Live Visual Tree during runtime, with a filter applied to only show text boxes. So both text boxes are in the same grid:

First textbox:
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />

Theme during runtime:

Second text box:
<TextBox Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

Style during runtime:

What is discovered so far:

This happens only to the first text box that appears in the XAML code. If I move the code, not the position in the grid, the other text box loses its style. So this feels like a bug.
It only happens when you have a style using BasedOn.
It only happens when you do not add a key to the style.

Any ideas on how this could happen? The style works fine in the designer and also works when I comment+uncomment the style during runtime with Hot Reload.
Edit: I left out the style on purpose initially, but here it is. Because this is for a plugin that runs inside another process, the default app.xaml does not work and we add the app style to each window.
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="/Company.Product;component/Windows/Theme.xaml" />
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                   <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
               </Style>
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

And in Theme.xaml:
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 5"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>


Can you also share the code of the style? This might be helpful

Sure, I added the style to the post.

I had the same problem while using MahApps. Can you share your main window xaml code (if it is in the main window), and app.xaml.cs code  and theme.xaml (all xaml code that is relevant) ?

I think your TextBox was modified once by your plugin, and then again by your style. I think if you remove BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" you should have the same style on all your textboxes, this should confirm my hypothesis.

That is on purpose, I want to add the Height property to the style from Theme.xaml and apply the combined style to all text boxes in the window. If you remove the BasedOn, the margin and vertical alignment are not applied. I don't think the style code matters because it only fails for the first object in this window. I added a hidden text box at the top of my window to fix the styling of the first visible text box, which is a bonkers workaround.

It "looks" like a "timing / ordering" issue. References to "TextBox" is causing "resources" to be "loaded" (?) but not necessarily in the order one is anticipating. A "race" condition (somewhere) perhaps.
